# Why does socket.emit repeat after jquery trigger is dynamically updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to update (or change) the content of the div ("display-holder") shown in the client side code, this div contains html and jQuery that calls a function outside the div that uses socket.emit, but once I replace this div content, the function with the socket.emit fires multiple times, also I'm using the off(), and unbind() functions but they don't seem to work. Is there any way to replace dynamically the div (display-holder) content and have the socket.emit firing only once?

client-side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Help!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    //Globals
    var displayCounter = 1;

    //Socket.io client side

      var socket = io('http://localhost');


      socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#message-displayer').append("<b> Server says: </b>"+data.msg+"<br>");

      });
      socket.on('client-answer', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#message-displayer').append("<b> Server says: </b>"+data.msg+"<br>");
        socket.emit('message', { msg: 'my data from client' });
      });

      //emitter function
      function sendData(data){
        socket.emit("client-message", { msg:data });
      }
    </script>

    <style> 

        #display-holder{
          position: absolute;
          margin: auto;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 500px;
          height: 300px;
          background-color: #ccc;
          border-radius: 3px;
          text-align:center
        }
        .display-holder-nodes{
         display: inline-block;
         border: 1px solid black;
         width: 95%;
        }
        button, input{ 
         width: auto;
         height: auto; 
         padding: 10px; 
         margin-top: 16px;
        }
        #message-displayer{ height:70%; overflow-y: scroll;}
        #control-panel{ height:25%; text-align:center;}

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="display-holder">
        <div id="message-displayer" class="display-holder-nodes"></div>
        <div id="control-panel" class="display-holder-nodes">
            <input type="text" id="clientInput">
            <button id="sendMessage">Send message</button>
            <button id="changeDisplay">Change display</button> 
        </div>
        <script>
        //jQuery handlers (will be replace when clicking "#changeDisplay" btn)

            $(document).on('click', '#sendMessage', function(){
                 $('#message-displayer').append("<b> You said: </b>"+$('#clientInput').val()+"<br>");
                sendData($("#clientInput").val());
                 $('#clientInput').val('');
            });

        </script>
    </div>


<script>
    //jQuery handlers 

    $(document).on('click', '#changeDisplay', function(){
        displayCounter++;
        //html and jquery to be inserted dynamically
        $("#display-holder").empty().off().unbind().html('  <div id="display-holder">'+
        '<div id="message-displayer" class="display-holder-nodes"><h3>Dislplay #'+displayCounter+'</h3></div>'+
        '<div id="control-panel" class="display-holder-nodes">'+
            '<input type="text" id="clientInput">'+
            '<button id="sendMessage">Send message</button>'+
            '<button id="changeDisplay">Change display</button> '+
        '</div>'+
        '<script>'+
            '$(document).on("click", "#sendMessage", function(){'+
                ' $("#message-displayer").append("<b> You said: </b>"+$("#clientInput").val()+"<br>");'+
                 'sendData($("#clientInput").val());'+
                ' $("#clientInput").val("");'+
            '});'+
        '</sc'+'ript>'+
    '</div>');
    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

server-side

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80, function(){
    console.log('App listening on port 80');
});

function handler (req, res) {

  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}



io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('news', { msg: 'hello client' });


  socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log('Client says: ', data);

  });

  socket.on('client-message', function (data) {
    console.log('Client says: ', data);
    socket.emit('client-answer', { msg: 'You sent me: '+data.msg });
  });

});
```

Comment: You should have no `display-holder tag` inside `$("#display-holder").html`, you are putting display holder inside display holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching the event to `document` and removing events attached to `display_holder`.

---

As said by the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object

---

Change the `.on()` to `$("#display_holder").on('click'`